# Is execution_guard_enabled officially supported feature?

Tags: neo4j

I just want to ask if execution_guard is supported feature in neo4j?

The reason I ask is the following:
It looks like it is really helpful to configure neo to terminate all queries longer than some threshold and we want to have it in our application. But I have not found any notes about this in neo4j documentation, and I do not know if it will/won't be changed without further notice in future...

We are currently using neo4j-1.8.2, but we also have plans to move to more recent version of neo4j in the nearest future.

Thanks,
Denys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guards are a not supported feature in Neo4j. Since they are not part of the documentation or the public API they are potentially subject to change in any new release. However they have not changed from 1.8 -> 1.9 and will work in 2.0 as well.

Comment: I think execution_guard does not seem to work in neo4j community version 2.1.2